# Issue faced while using xsl:for-each loop to query instead of select="expr" in xsl:variable

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am getting different counts for variable $var when I use 2 different techniques to select elements:-

```
<xsl:variable name="var" select="$doc//ns:abc | $doc//ns:xyz"/>

<xsl:message select="count($var)"/>
```

gives apprpriate count

However

```
<xsl:variable name="var" >
    <xsl:for-each select="$doc//ns:abc | $doc//ns:xyz">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:message select="count($var)"/>
```

gives 1

How to get the appropriate count using for-each loop too. As I want to store elements in sorted order which can only be done by using xsl:sort/ in xsl:for-each/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of

```
<xsl:variable name="var" >
    <xsl:for-each select="$doc//ns:abc | $doc//ns:xyz">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

the value of the variable is a single document fragment node containing a copy of the elements you select.

You would need to use an `as` attribute on the `xsl:variable` and `xsl:sequence`

```
<xsl:variable name="var" as="node()*">
    <xsl:for-each select="$doc//ns:abc | $doc//ns:xyz">
        <xsl:sequence select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

or simply

```
<xsl:variable name="var" as="node()*">
    <xsl:sequence select="$doc//ns:abc | $doc//ns:xyz"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

to select the nodes from the input document as a sequence of nodes.

Note that XPath 3 has a `sort` functions also so perhaps even if you need to sort input nodes you don't need XSLT elements like `xsl:for-each/xsl:sort` or `xsl:perform-sort/xsl:sort` but can simply use the `sort` function in your `select` XPath expression.

Comment: Or use `count($var/*)`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, well, yes, if we restrict it to strictly answering the question "How to get the appropriate count using for-each loop". But for the whole problem I prefer to suggest to use the `as` attribute and make sure `xsl:sequence` is used to avoid the overhead of copying nodes.

Comment: I wasn't trying to contradict you (in fact, I was in the middle of writing an answer very similar to yours when you posted), just to mention another possibility - which also adds another illustration of the basic issue here.